# How to set Highlighted Adjusts Image property of Navigation bar's right bar item button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uinavigationbar

In `UINavigationBar` I've set right bar item image in `storyboard`. It's `highlighted` when tapped. I want to disable highlighting by setting "Highlighted Adjusts Image" to false. How to access this property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)` for image to solve this:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "picture")!.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: nil)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem
```

Comment: No, it just affects image appearance. As you can also see, it's still a UIBarButtonItem.